# How to background repeat jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to not repeat background.

Here is my code

```
$("body").css({background : "url(../img/bgr.png)", backgroundRepeat: 'none'});
```

The problem is that the background repeats. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `background` sets all background-related options while `background-repeat` is just a single one - which is overridden by `background`.

The best solution is using `backgroundImage` for the background image and `backgroundRepeat` for the repetition since that will not touch other background options which might already exist.

Another solution would be setting `background` to `url(...) no-repeat`

Comment: You don't have to wait for upvoting - just for accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give `backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'` a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$("body").css({background : "url(../img/bgr.png) no-repeat" });
```

for dynamically,

```
$("body").css({background : 'url('+imageUrl+') no-repeat' })
```

Answer (score 0):

use css class:

css:

```
.bg {background:url(../img/bgr.png) no-repeat;}
```

js:

```
$('body').addClass('bg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").css({background : "url(../img/bgr.png)", background-repeat: 'no-repeat'});
```